# export certain elements from JSON to XLS

Tags: python, json, pandas, xls

I currently read a JSON data structure from an API. This structure is kind of nested:

```
my_json={
"data": {
    "allSites": {
        "activeLicenses": 0,
        "totalLicenses": 1100
    },
    "sites": [
        {
            "accountId": "12345",
            "accountName": "ACME INC",
            "activeLicenses": 0,
            "createdAt": "2021-01-12T20:04:12.166693Z",
            "creator": null,
            "creatorId": null,
            "expiration": null,
            "externalId": null,
            "healthStatus": true,
            "id": "12345",
            "isDefault": true,
            "name": "Default site",
            "registrationToken": "rznwzrsnbwrn==",
            "siteType": "Paid",
            "sku": "Core",
            "state": "active",
            "suite": "Core",
            "totalLicenses": 0,
            "unlimitedExpiration": true,
            "unlimitedLicenses": true,
            "updatedAt": "2021-01-12T20:04:12.165504Z"
        },
        {
            "accountId": "67890",
            "accountName": "DE | C12345 | ACME Inc",
            "activeLicenses": 0,
            "createdAt": "2021-01-15T12:53:05.363922Z",
            "creator": "John Doe",
            "creatorId": "567837837",
            "expiration": "2021-01-31T02:00:00Z",
            "externalId": "C12345",
            "healthStatus": true,
            "id": "3268726578",
            "isDefault": true,
            "name": "Default site",
            "registrationToken": "dghmntzme6umeum==",
            "siteType": "Paid",
            "sku": "Core",
            "state": "active",
            "suite": "Core",
            "totalLicenses": 1000,
            "unlimitedExpiration": false,
            "unlimitedLicenses": false,
            "updatedAt": "2021-01-15T12:53:05.878138Z"
        },
        {
            "accountId": "769i376586256",
            "accountName": "ACME Inc 2",
            "activeLicenses": 0,
            "createdAt": "2021-01-16T10:48:55.629903Z",
            "creator": "Jon Doe",
            "creatorId": "267267",
            "expiration": null,
            "externalId": null,
            "healthStatus": true,
            "id": "467267267",
            "isDefault": false,
            "name": "IT PoC",
            "registrationToken": "sthmetuzmstmwsu==",
            "siteType": "Trial",
            "sku": "Complete",
            "state": "active",
            "suite": "Complete",
            "totalLicenses": 100,
            "unlimitedExpiration": true,
            "unlimitedLicenses": false,
            "updatedAt": "2021-01-16T10:48:55.940332Z"
        }
    ]
},
"pagination": {
    "nextCursor": null,
    "totalItems": 3
}
```

}

I'm only interested in the elements within "sites", everything else can be ignored for the time being.
In the corresponding XLS the Column Names should be the item names like accoutID, accountName, etc.

I'm able to get everything exported to CSV or XLSX with Pandas, but how to I limit the export to "sites" only and get the column headers?

thanks

---edit
while trying below suggestions, I get keyword errors.

My code looks like:

```
 r = requests.get("https://URL/web/api/v2.1/sites?limit=999&sortBy=name&states=active", headers={"Authorization":token})
data = r.json()

print(data)

sites = data['allSites']['sites']
result = pd.DataFrame(sites)
print(result)
```

the result of "data" the content mentioned above.

when I now do

```
sites = data['allSites']['sites']
result = pd.DataFrame(sites)
print(result)
```

I get back an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
> pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
> File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
> exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
> File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/S1MSSPProvisioning/getStats.py", line 45, in 
> main()
> File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/S1MSSPProvisioning/getStats.py", line 29, in main
> sites = data['allSites']['sites']
> KeyError: 'allSites'

Comment: Have you tried using `data['allSites']['sites']`?

Comment: this gives me a: df = pd.DataFrame(data['sites'])
KeyError: 'sites' error

Comment: It must be `data['allSites']['sites']` not `data['sites']`

Comment: @IoaTzimas tried that as well (see question edit above)

Comment: I added a name (my_json) to your data structure so that it will be more clear. Try this now:
`my_json['data']['sites']`

Comment: @IoaTzimas that was it (kind of). I had to start with "data", not with "allSites", I had misread what you have written below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired data by using the following:

```
sites= my_json['data']['sites']
```

and create a dataframe with:

```
res=pd.DataFrame(sites)
```

Output will be:

```
>>>print(res)

       accountId             accountName  ...  unlimitedLicenses                    updatedAt
0          12345                ACME INC  ...               True  2021-01-12T20:04:12.165504Z
1          67890  DE | C12345 | ACME Inc  ...              False  2021-01-15T12:53:05.878138Z
2  769i376586256              ACME Inc 2  ...              False  2021-01-16T10:48:55.940332Z

[3 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: That works and exports to excel fine, thanks a lot! Any quick tip on how I can choose the columns I want to export to excel (I don't need all of them).

Comment: Just select the columns you need while saving to excel, for example: `df[['col1', 'col2', ...]].to_excel()`

Comment: and if I may ask: how can I then "add" a column where the content is just the first two digits from "accountName", i.e. "DE" in the example above

Comment: You can use: `df['new']=df['accountName'].str[:2]`